# What is "writes like a hippopotamus"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Excerpted from [http://thesmartset.com](http://thesmartset.com/anatomy-of-wonder/)

> It’s a pity that Frye isn’t around to classify A Song of Ice and Fire. He might have termed it a quest-romance where subtlety and complexity are sacrificed in favor of stark dialectical contrasts suggestive of folklore and allegory. Nor would it have bothered him that George R. R. Martin **writes like a hippopotamus** and that millions of readers love his books for precisely that reason.

What is it like to write like a hippopotamus?

Comment: How well do you think hippopotamus writes?

Comment: @Catija They can't write obviously.

Comment: It is said, the hippopotamus explores his subject from top to bottomamus.

Comment: I find it a poor metaphor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hippopotamus is generally considered to be an animal of very great bulk but very little grace. (That's why the [hippopotamuses in tutus dancing classical ballet in *Fantasia*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEjPDS8Jp1E) are so funny.)

The author ascribes (quite accurately) an analogous literary style to George R.R. Martin: the *Ice and Fire* series is very long, and although the story is gripping, the local writing is ponderous and plodding.

Comment: What do you make of "Nor would it have bothered him..."?  Is that use of **nor** valid? Does it hinge on "Frye isn't around"?